# "Tracking Prevention blocked access to storage for" error when hosting my outlook add-in in S3 preventing loading of officeJS library

Tags: javascript, office-js, microsoft-edge, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Good Day, My outlook add-in works perfectly localy, however when I host it on S3 I am getting the following error.
[image: Error]

Based on some research, it seems that [this is a result of a security setting in edge.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/tracking-prevention-blocked-access-to-storage-for/)
Blocking the javascript is preventing my whole application from loading anything.
The nature of it being an add-in prevents me from changing this security setting.

**How can I load my javascript in such a way as will not trigger this security measure?
**

Comment: How does your add-in work, exactly? Is there a reason you can't provide the JS files in your add-in package?

Comment: [Here is Microsoft's documentation for Edge's Tracking Prevention feature intended for developer audiences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/tracking-prevention), it explains how you can mitigate tracking-prevention, and also states it can be due to misclassification of your domain-name. That said, I still think avoiding any and all external-hosting (like S3) is the best option, because if your AWS account ever expires, someone else could claim your S3 account name and start serving malware...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What is the recomended way to host my add-in

Comment: It explains how you can mitigate tracking prevention at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/tracking-prevention